# Get the return values from python's tkinter menu

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

So this is how my program flows. User loads a file, through the menu and loadFile function will be called.

[image: Figure 1]

```
def loadFile():
    dictList = defaultdict(list)
    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("text files","*.txt")])
    #process the file content and store in dictList
    return dictList
```

Now in the GUI, when user clicks on the load file menu, load file will get called. Since loadfile returns me a dictList object, which I need it for further processing later. How do I get the returned object without using global variables? I'm not coding in object-oriented way either.

```
fileMenu.add_command(label="Load File", command=loadFile)
```

Comment: Love when people ignore both -- global variables and OOP!

Comment: Basically, I want to save the dictList that loadfile() return. How do I save that? loadFile() will be called when user clicks "load file" on the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it without using a global variable. The variable has to be stored in a way that it can be accessed from multiple functions. Since you're not using objects, your only<sup>1</sup> choice is to use a global variable.

<sup>1</sup> technically speaking, it's not your *only* choice. You could use a database of some sort, or write the value to disk, but it's the only practical choice in this scenario.

Comment: That's some pretty bad limitation. What should I do if I got functions to call that require arguments? Does OOP solves this?

Comment: @ysj: it's not a limitation, it's just how programming works. For a function to use a value defined in another function, it must be passed in or it must be in some sort of shared context. Since you're asking about a function called in response to an event (versus calling it directly) you _must_ store it in a way that other functions can access it. It's a somewhat immutable fact about programming that you can't use a value if you can't see it.